# Item continúa modificandose al añadirlo a una lista con AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lista

Como pueden ver en la siguiente imagen, cuando añado un elemento, o modifico el input, tambien se modifica el elemento que había añadido.

[image: Al momento de agregar una tarea se edita la que ya estaba]

Aqui el html:

```
<form ng-submit="addItem(item)">
   <input type="text" ng-model="item.id" placeholder="Agrega una tarea">
</form>

<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item" class="card">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-10" style="padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:10px;">
            <label class="checkbox" style="padding:0px">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="groupe0.checked" ng-checked="groupe0.checked" ng-change="">
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-70" style="padding-top:2%">
            Item {{ item.id }}
        </div>

        <div class="col col-20" style="font-size:70%">
           23-Jul-2016
        </div>
     </div> 

     <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="onItemDelete(item)"></ion-delete-button>    
 </ion-item>
```

Este es el método en el controller:

```
 $scope.addItem = function(item){
    console.log(item);
    if(item != null) {
      $scope.items.push(item);
      item = '';
    }
  }


 $scope.items = [
    { id: 0 },
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 }
 ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema se debe a que estas usando exactamente el mismo objeto en `$scope.item` y `$scope.items.push(item);`.

Aunque el objeto `item` se encuentre almacenado en un arreglo sigue siendo la misma dirección de memoria para ambos y por lo tanto cualquier modificación a uno se reflejará de inmediato en el otro.

La solución es muy sencilla, usa `angular.copy` para crear un clon antes de añadirlo

```
$scope.items.push(angular.copy(item));
```

De esa forma cuando `ng-model` modifique el valor de `$scope.item` no se estará refiriendo al mismo objeto.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
  .controller('ListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.item = {};

    $scope.items = [{
      id: 0
    }, {
      id: 1
    }, {
      id: 2
    }, {
      id: 3
    }];

    $scope.addItem = function(item) {
      console.log(item);
      if (item != null) {
        $scope.items.push(angular.copy(item));
        item.id = '';
      }
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.id" placeholder="Agrega una tarea">
    <button class="button button-positive" type="button" ng-click="addItem(item)">Agregar</button>
  </form>
  <ion-scroll>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item" class="card">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-10" style="padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:10px;">
            <label class="checkbox" style="padding:0px">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="groupe0.checked" ng-checked="groupe0.checked" ng-change="">
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col col-70" style="padding-top:2%">
            Item {{ item.id }}
          </div>

          <div class="col col-20" style="font-size:70%">
            23-Jul-2016
          </div>
        </div>

        <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="onItemDelete(item)"></ion-delete-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-scroll>
</div>
```